# How to show data without ID in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I am showing some data to the user:

```
{
"id": 3,
"name": "AB:11",
"description": "AB:11 is an Imperial Black Barley Wine brewed with ginger, black raspberries and chipotle peppers. A 12.8% rollercoaster of ginger zestiness and chipotle smokiness, all bound together with dark berry tartness and the decadent residual body of a Black Barley Wine.",
"method": {
    "id": 3,
    "mash_temp": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "temp": {
                "value": 68,
                "unit": "celsius"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

But, I want to show it without "method" I only need to show what is inside "mesh_temp" field,so it would be something like this:

```
"id": 3,
"name": "AB:11",
"description": "AB:11 is an Imperial Black Barley Wine brewed with ginger, black raspberries and chipotle peppers. A 12.8% rollercoaster of ginger zestiness and chipotle smokiness, all bound together with dark berry tartness and the decadent residual body of a Black Barley Wine.",
"mash_temp": [
   {
       "temp": {
       "value": 68,
       "unit": "celsius"
        }
   }
  ]
}
```

Also, like you can see in first example I don't want to show id of the mesh_temp

Those are my Entities:

- Beer: [Beer class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsrXj.png)
- Method: [Method class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpzfB.png)
- Mash Temp: [MashTemp class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0J1N.png)
- Temp: [Temp class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lkxC.png)

So just to summarize: I want to show only: id, name, description and mash_temp field (without id). Any advices how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a DTO that is used in the response on your API with exactly the attributes you want. This is in fact a suggested pattern exactly because of use cases similar to this one: when your internal model is different from the model you want to make available via your API.

Comment: You can see here a relevant example: https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: I tried with DTO but the problem is because my MashTemp field is returning the null

Comment: You need to map the original `MashTemp` to your DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Just like I answered your other question, I would suggest a DTO approach with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views: [How to show data to user with DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906400/how-to-show-data-to-user-with-dto/69079444#69079444)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model class as shown below and set the required fields

```
public class MyData {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private List<MashTemp> mash_temp;
```

}

```
class MashTemp {
private String temp;
private Integer value;
private String unit;
```

}