# How to show data to user with DTO

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, rest

This is the data that I am currently showing to the user:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "AB:11",
  "description": "AB:11 is an Imperial Black Barley Wine brewed with ginger, black raspberries and chipotle peppers. A 12.8% rollercoaster of ginger zestiness and chipotle smokiness, all bound together with dark berry tartness and the decadent residual body of a Black Barley Wine.",
  "method": {
  "mash_temp": [
    {
        "temp": {
            "value": 68,
            "unit": "celsius"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I don't need this "method" field. I tried to show data with DTO which looks like this:

```
public class Beer {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String description;
   private Method method;
   private List<MashTemp> mashTemp;
   private Temp temp;
   
   // getters & setters
```

My DTO is giving me back a response like a:

```
"id": 1,
"name": "Bitch Please (w/ 3 Floyds)",
"description": "This limited edition American Barley Wine was brewed in collaboration with 3 Floyds Brewery. This beer had all the warm, boozy and smoky aspects of an Islay Scotch whisky with the sweet malt and devastatingly bitter attributes of a barley wine. Peat smoke features prominently, backed up with a complex fruity hop profile.",
"method": {
    "mash_temp": [
        {
            "temp": {
                "value": 65
            }
        }
    ]
},
"mashTemp": null,
"temp": null
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following classes:

```
public class BeerDto {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String description;
   private List<MashTempDto> mashTemp;
}

public class MashTempDto {
   private TempDto temp;
}

public class TempDto {
   private Integer value;
}
```

Now you need to map your original `Beer` object to `BeerDto` (the same is true for `MashTempDto` and `TempDto`) which you will then make available in your API.

Comment: This is clear. But I am confused how to map all of these in Controller. This is how my Controller method looks now:                                                
        @GetMapping("/beers/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<BeerDTO> getById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Beer beer = beerServiceImpl.findById(id);

        // convert entity to DTO
        BeerDTO beerDTO = modelMapper.map(beer, BeerDTO.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(beerDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Comment: `modelMapper` should be the one doing the trick. You can either rely on a library (like MapStruct) or you can map it on your own. To be honest I find MapStruct too cumbersome to use when the mapping is not simple so I would go with manual mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Beer.class)
public interface BeerDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
    String getDescription();
    Set<MashTempDto> getMashTemp();

    @EntityView(MashTemp.class)
    interface MashTempDto {
        TempDto getTemp();
    }
    @EntityView(Temp.class)
    interface TempDto {
        Integer getValue();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`BeerDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, BeerDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<BeerDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!