# DTO and Entities mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, rest, mapping, dto

I am building a Spring Rest Application, I need help with DTO's and parsing a result to a endpoint

- This is json that I return at the moment to the endpoint:

  ```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ella - IPA Is Dead",
    "description": "2015 IPA is Dead Series. Supremely floral, this hugely under-rated hop is related to Galaxy and was first cultivated in the Australian state of Victoria.",
    "method": {
        "mash_temp": [
         {
             "temp": {
                 "value": 65
             }
         }
    ]
   }
  }
  ```

I don't want to return "method" from this json, I just need "id", "name", "description", "mash_temp" - so it should look like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Ella - IPA Is Dead",
  "description": "2015 IPA is Dead Series. Supremely floral, this hugely under-rated hop is related to Galaxy and was first cultivated in the Australian state of Victoria. Initially given the same name as a certain Eurolager, their lawyers got involved and the St- prefix was dropped. Ella displays subtle notes of spice, but is fundamentally a truly floral bouquet, redolent of the Southern Hemisphere.",
  "mash_temp": [
   {
      "temp": {
         "value": 65
         }
      }
  ]
}
```

Those are the entities that I am using now:

- Beer Entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Beer implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "beer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
      private Integer id;

      @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
      private String name;

      @JsonProperty("description")
      @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
      private String description;

      @JsonProperty("method")
      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private Method method;
  }
  ```
- Method Entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Method implements Serializable
  {

       @JsonIgnore(value = true)
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Integer id;

       @JsonProperty("mash_temp")
       @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinColumn(name = "mash_temp")
       private List<MashTemp> mash_temp = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  ```
- MashTemp Entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class MashTemp implements Serializable
  {

      @JsonIgnore(value = true)
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Integer id;

      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private Temp temp;

      @ManyToOne
      private Method method;
  }
  ```
- Temp Entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Temp implements Serializable
  {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Integer id;

      private Integer value;

      @JsonIgnore(value = true)
      private String unit;

      @OneToOne
      private MashTemp mashTemp;
  }
  ```

Does anyone know how to create DTO's from this Entities but without "method" field?

- Also this is my Controller:

  ```
  @GetMapping("/beers")
  public ResponseEntity<Set<Beer>> getAllBeers()
  {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(beerService.getAllBeers(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("/beers/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Beer> getById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
      Beer beer = beerService.findById(id);

      return new ResponseEntity<>(beer, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
  ```

Comment: You can manually Return a map by removing that key or by constructing a new dto from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show data to user with DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906400/how-to-show-data-to-user-with-dto)

Comment: A bit. So I should map all of these 3 dto's and after that return beerDTO inside method in Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html). You can put it on the `method` field in the `Beer` class, and then the properties of the `Method` class are serialized directly on the same level as the ones from `Beer`.